# Need to print the binomial coefficients using pascals triangle (x+y)

Tags: c++, syntax

The question is this

Binomial coefficients are the numeric factors of the products in a power of a binomial such as (x + y)^n . For example, (x + y)^2 = x^2 + 2 x y + y^2 has the coefficients 1 2 1. Binomial coefficients can be calculated using Pascal's triangle:

Each new level of the triangle has 1's on the ends; the interior numbers are the sums of the two numbers above them. Write a program that includes a recursive function to produce a list of binomial coefficients for the power n using the Pascal's triangle technique.

Here is the code. I need to get the output "1 2 1" is I input x to be 2 but the output is not correct. When i enter 2 i get the output 1 1 1

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int pascal(int n, int x){
    if ((n==0) || (n==1) || (n==x))
        return 1;
    else
        return pascal(n-1, x-1) + pascal(n, x-1);
}
int main()
{
    int x;
    cout << "Input the number of which you want to print the binomial coefficients : ";
    cin >> x;
    int n = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<x; ++i)
        cout << pascal(n, x) << " ";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pascals Triangle by recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659949/pascals-triangle-by-recursion)

Comment: What output *did* you get? And did you check x=0 and x=1 before you started worrying about x=2?

Comment: you do not ask any question

Answer (score 1):

change

```
if ((n==0) || (n==1) || (n==x))
```

to

```
if ((n==0) || (n==x))
```

and

```
for (int i=0; i<x; ++i)
    cout << pascal(n, x) << " ";
```

to

```
for (int i=0; i<=x; ++i)
    cout << pascal(i /*not 'n'*/ , x) << " ";
```